# Parsing json string from events(function) ajax in Full Calendar

Tags: json, function, fullcalendar

I have no clue on how to parse events in full calendar

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
 $.ajax({
  url: 'async/form.php?a=liste_consignes',
  datatype:'json',
  data: {
   // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
   start: start.unix(),
   end: end.unix()
  },
  success: function(msg) {
   //not sur then how to parse
    var events = msg.events;
    callback(events); //this gives error
  },
 });
}
```

PHP (part of)

```
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $cal['id'] = $row['consigne_id'];
        $cal['title'] = $row['contenu'];
        $cal['start'] = $row['date_consigne'];

    array_push($return_arr,$cal);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

PHP is returning

```
[{"id":"5","title":"consigne","start":"2019-03-03"},{"id":"6","title":"test","start":"2019-03-02"},{"id":"7","title":"test 2","start":"2019-03-02"}]
```

I tried several way from [events as json feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) but none of them are returning something

Answer (score 1):

PHP is returning an array. It doesn't have an `events` field. If your callback is meant to consume an array, simply call `callback(msg)`

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to convert json string from php to object

```
                      success: function(msg) {
                        var events = [];
                        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
                        $.each(data, function(i, item) {

                            events.push({
                                title: item.title,
                                start: item.start, // will be parsed
                                end: item.end, // will be parsed
                              });
                        });
                        callback(events);
                    }
```

Comment: You don't need the loop here, you're creating an identical structure to the one you've already got . You can just just do `callback (data);` once you've parsed it.